# SELECT only item with most recent date

Tags: date, select, plsql

I have the following table:

```
create table weights (
   ident int references users,
   dateW date,
   weight float,
   primary key(ident,dateW)
);
```

I wanna select only the weight from a given user (ident) with the most recent date. I have:

```
SELECT WEIGHT
FROM WEIGHTS
WHERE WEIGHTS.IDENT = 22 AND WEIGHTS.DATEW = (SELECT MAX(WEIGHTS.DATEW)
                                              FROM WEIGHTS);
```

But it's not doing what I want. Suggestions?

Comment: please, translate all your code from portugues to english so others can help you.

Comment: I can't understand your question, I see inconsistency between the queries, please translate as @eLRuLL says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT w.WEIGHT
FROM WEIGHTS w
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(DATEW) MaxDATEW
    FROM WEIGHTS 
) w1
    on w.DATEW= w1.MaxDATEW
WHERE w.IDENT = 22
```

Or you can apply `row_number()`

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT w.WEIGHT, row_number() over(order by w.DATEWdesc) rn
    FROM WEIGHTS w
    WHERE w.IDENT = 22 
) s
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you may have with your query is that the maximum date may be picked up from a different user, in which case you wouldn't get a result. The subquery should only get the maximum date for the same user.

```
SELECT WEIGHT
FROM WEIGHTS
WHERE WEIGHTS.IDENT = 22 
AND WEIGHTS.DATEW = (
    SELECT MAX(WEIGHTS.DATEW)
    FROM WEIGHTS
    WHERE WEIGHTS.IDENT = 22
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  max(WEIGHT) keep (dense_rank first order by datew desc) as latest_weight
FROM WEIGHTS
WHERE WEIGHTS.IDENT = 22;
```